# Global Manipulation of the Magnetic Field of Earth, More in the question itself

Tags: magnetic-fields

I was wondering if it might be possible to use the magnetic field of the earth as an object with which to send information...Would someone be able to cause and detect fluctuations in the magnetic field of the earth in order to send and receive data, or to do this locally by causing minor disturbances in the magnetic field in an area, such as your work place. I am not good at physics at all, so please try to simplify your answers, (Dont listen to this if you dont want to)!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you state:

> Would someone be able to cause and detect fluctuations in the magnetic
>   field of the earth in order to send and receive data

I suppose the answer is yes, maybe someday someone will be able to do this.  However this is far *far* beyond our current capabilities.  It's in the same bag of science fiction as time travel and anti-gravity.

Comment: Well, I am currently trying to send/receive data using Electromagnetic waves/fields. If you have two electromagnets, and you cause them to fluctuate in order to affect a magnetic device, (such as a Compass) and you set the two magnets on the east and west sides of said compass, while causing the compass to move toward East or West, If you have a sensor that turns East into 1, and West into 0, you could essentially give a computer a command in binary using this system... (I failed my English class don't judge any grammar mistakes :P)